# How to check between integers a & b, if inside the binary representation of a, you can find binary of b?

Tags: binary

I'm using this to read a two dimensional texture that has a binary mapping of colors, to represent the hidden z dimension. This is used for a shadowmap im trying to create. I use the red channel to represent the z dimension, and if there is light, it gets colored with 0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.08, etc.

I then query from withing a point in world space, and I try to deduct that if in indeed, there is light in this particular position. Each color value represents a z point in world space as so;
0.01 = 0,
0.02 = 1,
0.04 = 2,
0.08 = 3,

I query the said texture and end up with the red color value of 0.06 (so 0.02+ 0.04). In the context of my game world, this means that the light voxels at the z positions of 1 and 2, are supposed to be lit.

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Mvh8.png)

Is there some cool property to binaries that would allow this?

I was somewhat able to do a naive implementation of this, using the textures RGBA as the keys to Z, but it only allows for max 4 world layers.

[Naive thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdk8e.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Indeed this is not clearly written. From the title I infer that you are thinking of something on the lines "find whether there is a sequence 10101 in 00100101000101011011". Your image, however, implies that you are only interested whether certain bits are set in a given binary sequence (for which you just need to do a binary "and" operation with a "mask" having *only* those bits set). Or - you may be thinking of something entirely different. Can you please edit your question to make it clearer?

Comment: Ill try to clarify my intention more, im not very good at math language

Comment: Can you make more sense of it now?

Answer (score 0):

In most programming languages, if you have an integer `n`, the expression `n && (1<<i)` picks out the i-th binary digit. (You may need to look up the specific symbol used for the binary operations.) Is that relevant to your question?

Comment: I have see if HLSL has a thing like that

Comment: The bit-wise AND operation is often denoted by the single symbol & (i.e. not && but &). To test if a particular bit is set, you would use an expression like `(n&(1<<i)) != 0` or `((n>>i)&1) != 0`.